# How do i remove a class from a dynamically created list for an individual element in the list in vuejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, v-for

The click is removing the alert class for all the li's at once , I want to remove alert class for each of the li individually after click

**Template**

```
<ul>
  <li v-for= "(post, index) in posts" 
    :key="index" class=" lists alert" 
    @click="removeAlert(index)">
    {{ post.name }}
    {{ post.content }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
removeAlert(index){
 const items = this.$el.querySelectorAll('lists');
 
 items.forEach((item, index)=>{
    item.classList.remove('alert');
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `class-binding`.

As you can see I used a **map** to store which index of `li` is alert.

1. When click, it will call `toggleAlert` to update the `alertMap`
2. `isAlert` method will return the value(true/false) for you to determine the `alert` class need to be added or not.

```
<template>
<ul>
  <li v-for= "(post, index) in posts" 
    :key="index" class="lists" 
    @click="toggleAlert(index)"
    :class="{ alert: !!isAlert(index) }"
  >
    {{ post.name }}
    {{ post.content }}
  </li>
</ul>
</template>

<script>
new Vue({

  data: {
    alertMap: {}
  },

  methods: {
    toggleAlert: function(index) {
      const key = index.toString()
      if (alertMap[key]) alertMap[key] = true
      else alertMap[key] = false
    },
    isAlert: function(index) {
      const key = index.toString()
      return alertMap[key]
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

By the way, my answer was written in vue2, you can changed it to composition for vue3.